# What is the easiest way to find the gcd of two polynomials in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$? ($m$ is prime)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm

For example, find the gcd of $2x^5 + 4x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x+ 1$ and $x^6 + 3x^5 + 4x^3 + 3x + 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It does matter that the modulus is a prime, otherwise things are more complicated (and some things fail).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86265/how-to-find-the-gcd-of-two-polynomials?rq=1

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes I forgot to mention that m is prime. I fixed it. What is the easiest way in that case besides euclidean algorithm which would be long?

Comment: @zwim is that the easiest way?

Comment: @leakaf Easiest by what metric?  If by hand (manually) then the forward (augmented matrix) method described in the dupe links is usually the easiest.

Comment: Well other way would be factoring each polynomial in $\mathbb Z_n$ but Berlekamp algorithm is even worse to carry on manually than EE so I would say yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely the easiest way to find the greatest common divisor of two polynomials in one variable over a finite *field* (so, $\mathbb Z/p$ only for $p$ prime), is the Euclidean algorithm. It may not seem intuitive, but it is actually a very efficient algorithm.

Comment: There is an online version here with steps https://mathsci2.appstate.edu/~cookwj/sage/algebra/Euclidean_algorithm-poly.html